# TestNG testlistener - Possible to pass variables to retrieve in the ITestResult

Tags: automated-tests, testng

I would like to be able to pass a variable a string variable to the ITestResult so that I can do something with it on a pass and failure.

I have a build number that is pulled off the screen and stored in a build variable.  I then would like to be able to use this build variable after the test has passed or failed to report the results back to the database with this custom build text.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ITestContext#{s,g}etAttribute.